# How to hide Google reCaptcha V2 widget using JS?

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, recaptcha

How can I hide reCaptchaV2 widget using JS?

I'm implementing reCaptcha like this:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&amp;render=explicit" async="" defer=""></script>
<div id='recaptcha_element'></div>
<div class="g-recaptcha" id="widget"
data-sitekey="..my site key.."></div>
```

I'm trying to disable it in this way:

```
document.getElementById('recaptcha_element').disabled = true;
```

or

```
document.getElementById('widget').disabled = true;
```

^^It's not working either way. Any leads on this?

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS:

```
.g-recaptcha {
    opacity: 0.65;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

And when you're ready to enable it, just remove the class.